# GENETOS crash because of dmsynth.dll on Win8

Tags: technical-issues, genetos

I am trying to play [GENETOS](http://www.tatsuya-koyama.com/software/wg002_genetos_eng.html) on my Win8 64bit laptop. The game crashes randomly due to what I believe are audio playback errors (it happens when a lot of sound effects are playing).
The game reportedly works fine in older versions of Windows.

Here is the error entry as it shows in Events Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: GENETOS.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4b31d5be
Faulting module name: dmsynth.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x5010a507
Exception code: 0xc000001d
Fault offset: 0x00012886
Faulting process id: 0xdb4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf2e7f9fe923c9
Faulting application path: D:\Games\GENETOS_Ver1_00\GENETOS.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\dmsynth.dll
```

I have the latest DirectX and NVidia drivers. I also have Japanese set as the language for non-Unicode programs.

Can someone direct me on how to fix the error? I heard there was a similar error in Hotline Miami but I couldn't find what the devs actually did to fix it. Also, googling for "dmsynth.dll errors" returns a billion sketchy dll download websites.

E: I tried running the game as administrator and using the compatibility mode. Neither worked :(